# Changing the value of defined constants

Tags: c

I am writting a program in C and I am facing some difficulties..If I define a constant(for example # define MAX 100) can I change in some cases in the program its value?? In the main I wrote for example MAX=5, and when I run the program, I get the following: invalid lvalue in assignment .

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a *constant* then, eh?

Comment: Just to fact check you here, that sounds like a compile error, not an error you would get when running the program :)

Comment: #define is a preprocessor command. During the preprocessing while compiling, all instances of MAX in your code will be replaced by 100. It looks like you want something akin to a global variable or the need to define more constans.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate more on about what you want to achieve, then the answers can be more detailed and to the point.

Comment: I want to write a program where MAX is the dimension of array b. 
At the main program we are asked to give the dimension (let d ).But in the function I make some calculations with b where the dimension is still MAX, so I want to replace MAX with d, so that I don't have to make all these calculations on whole array with dimension MAX, when I only need the array with dimension d..

Comment: sounds like you want your arrays to be dynamic, in that case you need to take a look at malloc and friends. Preprocessor tokens are just replaced when compiling, it is a pure text replacement so you can't change those values although you could use them in an expression MAX - 5

Answer (score 2):

You can re-define the macro, using `#undef` and the `#define` it again. Not something I would recommend though, especially if done in a header file (as all files that `#include` the header file will have the new macro, and if you include the header files in the wrong order you will have the wrong value anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Since there are two different MAXs, the following code works better.

```
const int cond1_max = 100;
const int cond2_max = 5;
int my_max = 0;              // whatever works for you
```

And initialize your max as follows:

```
if(cond1)
    my_max = cond1_max;
else if(cond2)
    my_max = cond2_max;
else {
    // your backup plan
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this code.

```
#ifdefine MAX 
    #undefine Max 
    #define MAX 5
     ---Your code---
    #undefine MAX 
    #define MAX 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Macro should not be used this way. That's why it's a macro and not a variable.

What you need is global variables (http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node19.html).